# Opening a text file in html textarea on click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a text file in textarea section of document on user click. I have number of files from which a user can choose, files are stored in a folder on server-side. Please help me to write a code including html and javascript.

Comment: This site exists to ask people to help you fix your code and not to write the code for you.

Comment: What have you tried? Here on Stackoverflow we help you if you also done some work yourself.

Comment: I tried it using File API, But I am unable to assign 'value' attribute of textarea to a text file.

Comment: please post some code that you tried